# Copy structure data

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with function for read structure data from binary file which appears when Option Strict is On.

> ```
> Public Function arh_setup(ByVal rw As Boolean) As Integer
>     Dim retval As Integer = 0
>     Dim fnum As Integer = FreeFile()
>     Dim temp As ValueType = CType(New aSetup, ValueType)
> ```

```
    Try
        FileOpen(fnum, setup_file, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Shared, Len(asT))
        If rw Then
            FilePut(fnum, asT, 1)
        Else
            FileGet(fnum, temp, 1)
        End If
        FileClose(fnum)
    Catch ex As Exception
        retval = -1
    End Try

' Now is question here
' How to get data from temp to asT?? 
EDIT:
Solution is asT = CType(temp, aSetup)

    temp= Nothing        
    Return retval
End Function
```

asT is globally declared variable of type aSetup (structure) which should take data from temp which contain (properly) readed data.

Question is how to copy data from local temp variable to global asT variable, preferably without looping (byte by byte) or by looping if not possible otherwise?

Comment: This is so close to VB6 you might as well just call it VB6. Your problem would not exist if you just used the built in .NET methods such as IO.File.ReadAllBytes.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have situation "as is".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting:

```
asT = CType(temp, aSetup)
```

Also, don't set local variables to `Nothing` before exiting a method, it's completely pointless. And you should use .NET's `FileStream`s and such instead of VB6 compatibility methods to read files.

Comment: Compiler says: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'System.ValueType' to 'myProg.arh_Setup' Casting (everything with everything) also don't go.

Comment: @user973238: `arh_Setup`? Are you sure it says `asT = CType(temp, aSetup)`, then?

Comment: Sorry, YES! asT = CType(temp, aSetup) did work! Thank you guys very much!!